# jQuery ajax done() getting called multiple times

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, jquery-deferred

I have a form that the user will potentially submit multiple times. Below is the code contained in my `submit` event.

When the user submits the form the first time, all is well and good, the `done` callback gets executed once. On each following time they submit the form, the `done` callback gets executed however many times the form was submitted with the `data` parameter being the data from the most recent submission.

```
var $form = $(e.currentTarget);
$.ajax({
    url: $form.attr('action'),
    data: $form.serialize(),
    type: 'POST'
}.done(function(data) {
    if (data.success === true) {
        alert('success!');
    } else {
        alert(data.errors);
    }
});
```

What is going on? Am I doing something wrong or how can I fix it? I've never had this problem before and I'm not sure what is going on.

Comment: possible to get a http://jsfiddle.net/ with this in action?

Comment: We need to see the submit event code

Comment: I would guess that you are re-adding a new event handler each time through the form so they pile up and after 3 submissions, you have 3 event handlers that each get called.  You will have to either look at that code yourself or include it here so we can help further.

Comment: @jfriend00 I believe that is exactly what is happening. It seems like the `done` is binding to the form or something and staying there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, My bad. I was unknowingly binding the `submit` event to the form every time I showed it (it was normally hidden). I hadn't noticed that the whole request was getting sent multiple times, not just the `done` callback.

Answer (score 2):

Since I figured out the problem in my comment, I will turn that into an answer.

The most likely scenario is that you are rebinding your form submit event handler each time so your code is getting called once for each event handler that has been bound.  This would not only call `.done()` each time, but also be calling the `ajax()` function multiple times.

The place to fix this would be where you are binding the submit event handler.  It should be bound only once and not each time the form is used.